# How to submit facebook app for review

Tags: facebook-graph-api

We’ve created successful a bot and also can test with page token generated from facebook developer portal (the token must contain page_messagaging permission to be able to send reply message).

But when we submit to facebook to review, it seems they use real account to test and the token doesn’t contain page_messaging permission. (log from our server says: {“error”:{“message”:”Unsupported post request. Object with ID ‘me’ does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api”,”type”:”GraphMethodException”,”code”:100,”fbtrace_id”:”DPdtxdcTKaf”}})

The submission has been rejected 3 times now.
And have no solution now.

Anyone experience in this? Could you please help us resolve?

Really appreciate!

Comment: Anyone has experienced on this? Could you please share us? Thanks.